# Deleting closed questions

Tags: support, questions, vote-to-delete, self-delete

I searched before asking, and there are indeed similar questions, however I could not find one that matches exactly my situation. Feel free to point me to the right question answer / close this one, if you have better luck finding one.

I'm posting here, and not on meta.gaming.stackexchange, because I believe that the rules are the same for all sites, again, if that assumption is wrong, please feel free to let me know.

I asked [a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240151/why-do-you-need-all-four-base-classes). This question turned out to be a not so good question and was closed by the community. Because the question was not useful, and I could not improve it, I decided that I might as well delete it. When I choose "delete" I was prompted if I was really-really sure and that's usually a bad thing to delete questions with answers, but hey, what I'm deleting is a trash question that is also mine, why could this be bad? So I choose to proceed.

In response I got unspecific "the question cannot be deleted" message without any reason and an advise to flag for moderator attention.

So I flagged for moderator attention, and the flag was declined with the reason "it would be unfair to people who answered to delete it".

Now I'm completely confused. Could you please explain me

- 1) As a community do we care more about peoples rep then about site content and refuse to delete bad questions, only because some one answered them?
- 2) As a community do we want reward people who answer bad questions?
- 3) Can a message that a question cannot be deleted be made more user friendly and give *a reason* why the question cannot be deleted?

Comment: Weird, you should see red banner [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hhmyv.png), which give a clear reason why it can't be deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, it could be my mistake, now I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

1. No, we refuse to delete questions with *good* answers. People have put time into that, and they deserve the reward.
2. No, but if they put time into that, we shouldn't take it away. Once a bad question is closed, the better because people can no longer answer it. There are suggestions to reward closing, but none good enough to be implemented yet.
3. <s>Hmm I think this has been asked before</s>. Essentially, a question can't be removed if there is 1 or more answers with a score of 1 or more. I think I've seen a post asking for clarification before, but I can't find it now.